# stop the AWS Ec2 instance which does not have any user logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, powershell-4.0

I am looking for a method where I can stop EC2 Instances which does not have any users logged in. I have Windows env in AWS and I use python and Powershell. 
I already have script which just shut down the instance but it run once in a day. So I am looking for a solution through which I can check every hour and stop the instance which does not have any user on.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create powershell script to check for logged on user.

You can create an script which will be triggered on user sign-in / out. This script scheduling can be done via

task scheduler / 
group policy https://serverfault.com/questions/10746/run-script-when-user-logs-on-or-off /
Custom service

This script will update Dynamo db table via AWS cli / simple NodeJS code.

Step 2: Create Dynamodb table stream lambda function

This function will be invoked when an Dynamodb table entry is updated.

This function will check if the loggedin user count is 0 then via AWS SDK / cli it will shutdown the corresponding instance.

I hope this will help you.